# Pandas .loc to find certain index values taking too long. Any alternatives to my method?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm currently trying to find all rows of a csv that contain at least one of a list of key values. This is my current method:

```
name_index = []
basics = pd.read_csv('name.basics.csv')
basics_unprocessed = pd.read_csv('name.basics.csv')
for i,ID in enumerate(movie_title_ids):
    ind = tuple(basics_unprocessed.loc[basics_unprocessed['knownForTitles'].str.contains(ID)].index)
    name_index.extend(ind)
    try:
        basics_unprocessed.drop(ind[0], inplace=True)
    except:
        print('drop failed')
    if i%100 == 0:
        print(i)
```

The idea here is that the `name_index` list will contain all indices that contain at least one of the specified ID key values.

Ideally this code does what I need it to, but it is going to take a very long time as the size of the IDs list is several thousands and the csv file is a couple million lines. I haven't really used big data tools very much but am open to learning something if it will help me here. Any recommendations on making my code more efficient or another tool (my friend suggested maybe using spark or something might help)

Comment: Perhaps provide a [mcve] with some data that provides a clear example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) this entire operation. First, eliminate the need to do multiple finds and do them all at once, buy joining them with a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) where multiple options (or) are repeated with `|`. Note, I am assuming these movie title ids do not contain special characters, if so you will need to escape them. I believe that even with several thousand options, this will be much faster.

```
mask = basics.knownForTitles.str.contains('|'.join(movie_title_ids))
```

Then, you can filter out all rows where this is true, as this returns a [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) that you can index with.

```
basics = basics[~mask]
```

---

Also, your code already has a lot of redundant operations that would slow things down regardless of doing this iteratively.

```
for i,ID in enumerate(movie_title_ids):
    ind = tuple(basics_unprocessed.loc[basics_unprocessed['knownForTitles'].str.contains(ID)].index)
```

Here there is no need to locate the index of all of these items, as you are given a mask from which you can remove immediately.

```
    name_index.extend(ind)
    try:
        basics_unprocessed.drop(ind[0], inplace=True)
    except:
        print('drop failed')
```

you perform the drop of all collected items every time. What happens when indexes from the first drop are not there?

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. It was an especially dumb mistake of me not to vectorize the operation considering earlier in the code I did that for another function.

Comment: @MadhuM. Good to hear it worked for you, can you please accept the answer.